# how to split a string of data into different list views?

Tags: android, listview, split

Would I be able to split a string of data starting with `<NewData>` with several different objects inside such as `<Schedule>` ending in `</Schedule>` and then ending over all with a `</NewData>`. Split that into several list views each schedule in a different list view? quite difficult to explain so any thing I've missed just say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm I'll only give you a hint,

```
 String stuff = "<Schedule> save kittens </Schedule> " +
                             "<Schedule> and puppies </Schedule>" ;

 String [] result = stuff.split("<Schedule>");
 for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
 {
          if(result[i].length() > 0)
            Log.d("TODO", " - " + result[i].substring(0, result[i].indexOf("<")));
 }
```